# Automated tests for Core Data Migration

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, automated-tests, core-data-migration

I want to create automated tests for my Core Data model migration. I have three versions of the model - 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2. and I want to create a new database with every test, populate it with fake data and than migrate it to a newer version, testing for any errors along the way. How should I approach writing tests like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by loading model from `mom` instead of `momd` file. Example test looks like this:

```
func testMigarationFrom_1_0_To_1_1() {
    let modelUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("1.0", withExtension: "mom", subdirectory: "Model.momd")!
    let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelUrl)!
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)
    let databaseUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("Storage").URLByAppendingPathExtension("sqlite")
    try! coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: databaseUrl, options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true])

    let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator

    for i in 0..<10 {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("entity", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Entity
        entity.name = "test-\(i)"
    }

    let newModelUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("1.1", withExtension: "mom", subdirectory: "Model.momd")!
    let newModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: newModelUrl)!
    let newCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: newModel)

    do {
        try newCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: databaseUrl, options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true])
    } catch let error {
        XCTFail("Should migrate without error, got \(error)")
    }
}
```